# Time optimization for generating permutations (competetive programming)

Tags: c++, performance, optimization

I'm trying to optimize the speed of the competitive programming problem. So far I have ended up with this code.
The problem is about getting all permutations on N in lexicographic order.
Can you please suggest any ideas, if it is possible to make it run faster?

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    int v[9] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};

    do
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            printf("%d ", v[i]);
        printf("\n");
    } while(next_permutation(v, v+n));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well, when you measured, what was taking the longest time?

Comment: @AlanStokes The whole program takes about 7 ms (mean time), the best result was 6.52 ms
Looks like it's the permutations generation part, because there is a lot of recursion, and working time increases drastically when N increases

Comment: How long does it take without the `printf`s?

Comment: `next_permutation` is O(N); it's hard to see how you could improve on that.

Comment: Best mean time for N from 1 to 8 is about 14 ms using cin/cout

Comment: If you remove the I/O altogether, how long does it take? I would suspect that dominates. Also, why 8? If you're optimising something that takes 7ms you're wasting your time. What happens if N is 100?

Comment: @AlanStokes it's like 10 times slower for N=8 than for N=7

Comment: @AlanStokes it's kinda of my personal interest, rather than essential

Comment: Just a lazy thought but beating `next_permutation` at what it does, which is to just generate the next permutation, is probably not very practical. A higher-level algorithm which generates all the permutations might be able to spot some opportunities to reduce the work based on assumptions that can be made in *between* each permutation.

Comment: Actually what improved runtime drasicalli was implementing custom bufferized output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some techniques to try, not all will produce significant savings:

### Set compiler optimizations to high, for speed.

First, let the compiler try optimizing your code.  Print out the assembly language listing and see what the compiler did.  Incorporate those optimizations into C++ code (if possible).

### Use block (bulk) output.

For many applications, outputting is where most of the time is spent.

Try using `snprintf` to a character buffer, then at the end of the program, use a block write (`fwrite`) to write the character buffer to the output stream.

For most output streams, one large transaction is more efficient than many small transactions.

### Loop Unrolling

Repeat statements in the body of the loop to reduce the number of iterations.

Most processors dislike branch instructions because they either invoke costly branch prediction algorithms or cause the instruction pipeline to flush.  For example, eliminating a branch means no time wasted in the branch prediction.

In your case, this may not be significant as you make function calls within the loop.

### Specialize your formatted output

The `printf` function is optimized for generic output:  translating format specifications and outputting data.

You may save some time by writing your own conversion function that eliminates the translation of format specification.  For example, your function only outputs decimal, so you could write your own function that converts integer numbers to a text buffer, then outputs the text buffer (see `fwrite` or `puts`).

### Write your own permutation function

Again, the `std::next_permutation` is designed for genericity.  You may be able to write your own that is more specialized or optimized for this specific application.

Comment: Looks like, `std::next_permutation` is already pretty well optimized
Though, **block output** helped much. The program basically went through tests about 3-4 times faster.
Thank you for the detailed answer